# get report of folders and subfolders including given access from a Sharepoint site using power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am looking to create a report through power query that shows all the folders and subfolders from a Sharepoint site, including the names of people I have given access to and their access rights.
I would like to use power query for this.

With the command Folder.Contents I was able to get a list of folders. But I cannot get the rest of the information needed.

Comment: As a separate step, when I prepare a power query with get data from sharepoint online list, I got to the subfolders and the names of the people using the "title" and "RoleAssignments.Member.Title."

I was hoping that both steps could be somehow combined by using List.Generate or so...

Comment: Edit your question to post your code and lets see

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.